# Function Return Behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, confirm, alerts

I have an `<a href='...'>link</a>` that I want to invoke a custom warning if they click it and then either select an "OK" or "Cancel" button with the underlying in HTML taking the appropriate action. The default action if "OK" or nothing if "Cancel."

The code in the HTML code is:

```
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
<div>
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
</div>
</div>

<a href='sumcodehere' return onclick=\"javascript: return Warn.render(\'This operation cannot be reversed.\')\"><img></a>
```

The Javascript code is as follows:

```
<script>
function Warn() { 
    this.render = function(dialog) { 
    var winW = window.innerWidth; 
     var winH = window.innerHeight; 
     var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay'); 
     var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox'); 
     dialogoverlay.style.display = "block"; 
     dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px"; 
     dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px"; 
     dialogbox.style.top = "300px"; 
     dialogbox.style.display = "block"; 
     document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').style.background = "url('../images/warningHead.gif') no-repeat";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').style.height = "30px";
            document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').style.background = "#fbfab9";
     document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog; 
            document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').style.background = "#fbfab9";
     document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="return      Warn.ok(); return false">Go Ahead and Delete</button>&nbsp;<button onclick="return Warn.cancel(); return true">Get Me Out Of Here!</button>'; 
            return false;
}
this.ok = function() { 
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none"; 
            return true;
} 
this.cancel = function() { 
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none"; 
            return false;
}
```

I'm trying this in Firefox, and the behavior being exhibited is that either button brings up the warning dialog, but both buttons, when clicked, seem to be returning "false."

Comment: At first, there are a couple of problems with the HTML of `<a>`. There seems to be an unknown `return` attribute, unnecessary label and quoting errors in `onclick`. In JS part `this` in `Warn()` is not what you think it is. Looks like you're mixing [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) here.

Comment: OK... that's the feedback I need... what SHOULD it be to get it to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

At first the HTML needs to be fixed:

```
<a href="sumcodehere" onclick="return warn.render('This operation cannot be reversed.')">
    <img src="..." alt="..." />
</a>
```

(Removed unknown `return` attribute and fixed quoting of the `onclick` attribute.)

Then in JS, `Warn()` looks like a constructor function, use it as such, and [create a global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function):

```
var warn = new Warn();
```

Notice the small letter at the beginning of the variable name. The same variable is used in inline handler.

A better way to attach event listeners to elements is to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) method, though.

Comment: The reason for the quoting was because this is code being generated by a "print" statement inside of Perl code... because it is contained inside of quotes, the quotes must be escaped.

Comment: @D.LawrenceBarksdale Well, There was no mention about Perl in the post. Anyway, I've posted the final parsed HTML. Did you get the event listener to work?